# Springboard crash when launching apps

Tags: objective-c, ios10, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm trying to make a theos tweak that will blur the background and show a text field of password when user enters any application. The text field that I use is a custom text field class(JVFloatLabeledTextField). The code works just fine without the custom text field but when I add it, the springboard crashes.
Here is the code:

```
#import "JVFloatLabeledTextField.h"

typedef enum {
  SBIconLocationHomeScreen = 0,
  SBIconLocationDock       = 1,
  SBIconLocationSwithcer   = 2
} SBIconLocation;

@interface SBApplicationIcon
- (void)launchFromLocation:(SBIconLocation)location context:(id)arg2;
@end

%hook SBApplicationIcon

- (void)launchFromLocation:(SBIconLocation)location context:(id)arg2 {

  UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

  UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
  UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
  [blurEffectView setFrame:window.bounds];
  [UIView transitionWithView:window duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations: ^ {
      [window addSubview:blurEffectView];
  } completion:nil];
  blurEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [window addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[blurEffectView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurEffectView)]];
  [window addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[blurEffectView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurEffectView)]];

  JVFloatLabeledTextField *pwt = [[%c(JVFloatLabeledTextField) alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
  pwt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
  pwt.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Enter your password", @"")
                                                                     attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
  pwt.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  pwt.floatingLabelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f];
  pwt.floatingLabelTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  pwt.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  pwt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
  pwt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  pwt.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
  [UIView transitionWithView:window duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations: ^ {
      [window addSubview:pwt];
  } completion:nil];
  [window addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-210-[pwt(>=44)]"
                             options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                             metrics:nil
                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(pwt)]];
  [window addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[pwt]"
                             options:0
                             metrics:nil
                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(pwt)]];
  [window addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:pwt attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:window attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

}

%end
```

Can you tell me what is the problem in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: The SpringBoard crash log would surely help.